# Issue in sorting in array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to apply different sorting on my array but I am getting unexpected results. This is my array result:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Sony,HTC 
[1] => HTC 
[2] => AT&T 
[3] => Sony 
[4] => BlackBerry 
[5] => Nokia 
[6] => Toshiba 
[7] => Altori 
)
```

When I print this array using `sort($rows,SORT_ASC)` it displays `'1'.$rows` as the array that contains elements. Can anybody find what the problem here is?

I want to sort the array with different options like `(SORT_REGULAR,SORT_NUMERIC)`.

Comment: You should also show the exact code that you are using to help people provide better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) reorders the array but does not return its sorted form -- instead,  it modifies the original array in-place and returns a boolean success/failure flag. This flag has the value `true`, which PHP converts to `"1"` when you print it.

So instead of this:

```
print_r(sort($array));
```

You should do this:

```
sort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: what happend if i want to sort with sort($rows,SORT_DESC) ?

Comment: @Jan but i want to sort the array with different forms ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman: I don't understand what the problem is. You can pass whatever parameters you want to `sort`. Just don't print its return value.

Comment: @Jan Sorry for in complete information.I am trying like this sort($rows,SORT_DESC);
print_r($rows);
I think i have to work with custom code for it ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman: There is no `SORT_DESC` flag. Use `rsort` instead.

Comment: @Jan Thanks yeah rsort reverse the order.

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` function sorts the array passed

`echo sort($array)` is a wrong statement

instead:

if $array is unsorted use `sort($array)`

and then `print_r($array)` and see the result.

I hope this would be useful.

Comment: Ok i got some idea but when i try to print with sort($rows,SORT_DESC) ? nothing happend

Comment: you cannot give the 2nd parameter as SORT_DESC. please refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php for the parameters allowed.